# Data Services CSV Flat File there should be a column delimiter after column [n]

Tags: csv, delimiter, import-from-excel

I'm really struggling with this one. Data services (v14.2.3.549) keeps flagging up an error saying "A column delimiter was seen after column number <80> for row number <1> in file " it says this for what looks like every row it processes.

I've used the same settings as all the last files I imported, which are also CSV files. The files are exported from a web front end as excel then saved as csv. I tried opening the file with excel, clearing empty columns after end of data, in case there was anything in them, and rerunning to no avail.

I don't really know what to look for in the file so can anyone help me find out what I should be looking for so I can map my way to the problem. It seems that this problem is throughout this collection of files, as if I try importing using wild card on end of file name it comes up with same errors in other files.

Many thanks

Andrew

Comment: check what kind of line endings are used in the file. just a guess..

Answer (score 0):

I used "Adaptable Schema" set to "yes" in the file format definition to get around this error.